# Divide n Conquer (Secret Sharing through minimum calls)

Tags: java, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

> There are **n** number of students in a class. Teacher tells one secret to
>   each student. The only way to share the secret is through a phone
>   call. Using divide and conquer, design an algorithm to find the minimum
>   number of phone calls required so that each student get all the
>   secrets.

One of my friend asks me this. I put some time to make an sketch i.e. I will have an array of students , I'll break it recursively until I have one student and upon joining them back I'll make a count that a call has been made between these two.

While combining two pairs I'll count two calls and so on. This is the point which is troubling to me or may be here I am missing something.

```
X1 X2  (1 call)               
X3 X4 (1 call)

X1 -----> X3
X2 -----> X4 (2 more calls)
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Is each call from one student to one other student?  Then n-1 calls are needed, since each student except the one who was originally told the secret needs to receive his/her own call.

Comment: n-1 is the max ,like i have shown in example X1 and X2 after 1 call can have 2 secrets, now if X1 calss to X3 which already called X4 so then X1 got all 4 screts

Comment: Whoops, I misread -- I thought there was only one secret.  n-1 is definitely a lower bound, not an upper bound, in that case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimum scheme for n>=4 people to share all n pieces of information is 2n-4 as shown in this [paper](http://www.nieuwarchief.nl/serie5/pdf/naw5-2000-01-2-208.pdf).

The divide and conquer approach to this problem is illustrated as follows:

> For four persons
>   A, B, C and D, say, take conversations AB, and CD, followed by
>   AC and BD. For every additional person P, schedule one conversation
>   AP, before A, B, C and D interchange their knowledge,
>   and another conversation AP afterwards.

Comment: How is this scheme generalized to *n* people?

Comment: To add person n, make person n talk to person 1, then solve problem for n-1 people, then make person n talk to person 1 again.

Comment: I don't get it. So person 5, 6, 7 and 8, say, should all call person 1, then the 4-person scheme runs, then person 5, 6, 7 and 8 should talk to person 1 again?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz I dont know why but I am getting confuse that is there any effect of even and odd number of persons...plz guide me...like adding 1 person we need 4 more calls,while if we have another pair no. of calls are less

Comment: @SSH To add one more person we just need 2 more calls, one at the start and one at the end.  Whether the total is even or odd is irrelevant.